# Efficient way in SQL to compute a set of rows against all other rows?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, matrix

Let's say I have a table with data that looks like this:

```
d   user     val
1   1        .94
1   2       -.88
1   3        .24
1   4        .74
2   1        .35
2   2        .68
2   3       -.98
2   4        .62
3   1       -.81
3   2        .97
3   3        .29
3   4        ___ (this row doesn't exist in the database)
4   1        .76
4   2        .38
4   3       -.98
4   4        .15
5   1        .69
5   2        .27
5   3       -.49
5   4       -.59
```

For a given user (let's say 2), I would like the following output:

```
user    calc
1       -.102
3       .668
4       -.1175
```

Generalized:

```
user    calc
1       ((-.88 - .94) + (.68 - .35)  + (.97 - -.81) + (.38 - .76)  + (.27 - .69))  / 5
3       ((-.88 - .24) + (.68 - -.98) + (.97 - .29)  + (.38 - -.98) + (.27 - -.49)) / 5
4       ((-.88 - .74) + (.68 - .62)                 + (.38 - .15)  + (.27 - -.59)) / 4
```

Generalized Further:

```
user    calc
1       sum of (user2's d value - user1's d value) / count
3       sum of (user2's d value - user3's d value) / count
4       sum of (user2's d value - user4's d value) / count
```

To explain further, I'd like to obtain an output that shows everyone's relation to a given user (in this case user 2). In my actual dataset there are hundreds of unsorted distinct users and d values, but I've tried to simplify the dataset for this question.

Also, please note that not all user's have a d value, so it should only factor in matching sets. See how in the example above user 4 doesn't have a value for d=3, so that one is skipped in the calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A join and aggregation should work:

```
select
    t2.user, avg(t1.val - t2.val) as calc
  from my_table t1
  join my_table t2 on t1.d = t2.d and t1.user <> t2.user
  where t1.user = 2
  group by t2.user
```

Comment: Cool thanks! Going to try to adapt it to my purposes now but it looks like it's 90% there.

Comment: Ok this is working great and it's ALMOST perfect. The only remaining issue is that I'd like it to return -1 in case the two user's don't share any d's. You don't have to edit your answer if you don't want. I'm going to try to think on it for a bit. Thanks again!